# 'command not found: jest'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a test file like so: (I am using create-react-app)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/Calculator';

import { getAction, getResult } from './actions/'

import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />)
  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('displays the choosen operator', () => {
  const action = {
      type: 'GET_ACTION',
      operator: '+'
    };
  expect(getAction("+")).toEqual(action)
})

it('displays the typed digit', () => {
  const action = {
    type: 'GET_RESULT',
    n: 3
  };
  expect(getResult(3)).toEqual(action);
})

it('checks that the clickevent for getNumber is called',() => {
  const clickEvent = jest.fn();
  const p = shallow(<p data-n="1" onClick={clickEvent}>1</p>)
  p.simulate('click')
  expect(clickEvent).toBeCalled();
})
```

and a package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    // "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.3",
    "jest": "^22.4.3"
  }
}
```

when I run `jest --updateSnapshot` I get:

```
command not found: jest
```

[image]

but jest is installed.

Comment: Why did you comment out the test script that comes with create-react-app? That should run jest just fine for you.

Comment: I have tried yo update snapshots that failed but didnt work ("jest command not found" after running jest --updateSnapshot)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

`Jest` is installed, but is likely in your `./node_modules/.bin` directory.  You can append that to your command `./node_modules/.bin/jest --updateSnapshot`.  Since you already have `jest` as a `scripts` command in your `package.json` you can also run it with `npm test -- --updateSnapshot`.  npm automatically adds `./node_modules/.bin` to your path.

*update*: Newer versions of yarn will resolve node module bin scripts, so you can also just run `yarn jest {cmd}` and it should work.

Comment: what exactly npm test -- do in this case? where this -- documented?

Comment: `test` and `start` are special fields in `scripts' that can be executed without `npm run`. `npm test` is the same command as `npm run test`

Comment: If you have modified your package test script and want quick direct access to jest via your node modules you could also add a system link.
`ln -s ./node_modules/.bin/jest jest` and then use it with `./jest`

Comment: Documentation on above answer: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#using-with-npm-scripts

Comment: I just ran into this issue where I had been using jest on the CLI fine until suddenly jest was an 'unknown command'. Turns out I had used NVM to switch to a older version of node (10.13.0) and I think this switches the NPM version as well. Switching back to 10.17.0 fixed this issue for me. So I assume NPM adds ./node_modules/.bin to the path in later versions.

Comment: Why does `npm test` work on windows but not on linux? In neither system is `jest` installed globally but in windows it runs fine and in linux it says " jest: command not found"

Comment: do I need jest-cli to run `jest` in cmd? `npm t` should be fine, so why bother with `jest-cli` and add this package?

Answer (score 67):

I ran into similar issue. I fixed it by installing jest globally.

```
npm install -g jest
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I was able to execute the "jest" command after installing globally. If you don't have it installed globally you can use the "npx jest" command.

Comment: I would not advocate for solving path issues by installing npm modules globally. It creates a reliance on the host environment and can cause breakages in CI environments.

Answer (score 48):

You need to run it this way :

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest
```

or run `npm test`

Answer (score 23):

Install the Jest command-line interface (Jest CLI):

```
npm install --save-dev jest-cli
```

Then run the jest command. Working for me in a linux instance by docker on Windows 10.

Answer (score 14):

A way to solve the error is to use the "npx" command.

```
npx jest --version


npx jest --init
```

Answer (score 12):

I was getting `zsh: command not found: jest` after installing jest and trying to use the command `jest`. The solution that worked for me was running `npx jest`

Answer (score 8):

try using the command

```
npx jest <folder>
```

I ran into the same problem. I tried multiple solutions and this worked.

I also have jest CLI installed

you can install it by using this command in your shell

```
npm install --save-dev jest-cli
```

Comment: Many thanks! `npx jest tests` works well for me. The folder `tests` is at the same level as `package.json`.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, npm didn't install the `jest` command for some reason.

To fix this:

1. I deleted the `node_modules/jest` directory
2. Re-ran `npm install` and got the `jest` command installed.

Comment: When nothing helps delete node_modules, thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 3):

just use command

`npm test` or `npm t`

Answer (score 2):

Removing node_modules and running `npm install` again fixed this for me 
Also the "new" `npm ci` command can fix this as it deletes (or clears) node modules and performs a clean install each time, plus it's faster compared to manually deleting `node_modules` and re-installing

Answer (score 2):

My situation was caused by my git pipeline. I wasn't caching `node_modules` nor was I caching untracked files.

Ultimately I added

```
cache:
  # untracked: true
  key:
    files:
      - package-lock.json
  paths:
    - node_modules
```

to my pipeline .yml and violá

**Note**

*you can either use `path` OR `untracked`, [find out more about each](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) to see what works best for you*

Answer (score 1):

Just reload your bash config file after install jest:

```
source ~/.bashrc # on linux ?
source ~/.bash_profile # on macOs
```

Jest will be not recognized but executed with npx jest automatically

Comment: I believe this relies on jest installed globally

Answer (score 1):

I use `yarn`. Adding `jest` and `jest-cli` to node_modules did not make any difference with my attempts to run tests like `jest mytest.test.js`. In addition to mentioned steps, the following helped to get it running:

```
yarn jest mytest.test.js
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run `ln -s ./node_modules/.bin/jest jest`
and then run `jest --init`  it will work. Or you can install jest cli with `npm install --save-dev jest-cli` and then run `jest --init` it will also work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to install jest with yarn on a pipeline to run tests and since I had jest installed as a `devDependency` it wasn't installing on yarn install.

I found this bug on GitHub https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2739 that it seems that Yarn will not install devDependencies when NODE_ENV=production.

I just needed to change the NODE_ENV and after that, it was working, otherwise, run it like this:

```
yarn install --production=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and was able to solve it by running npm install

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. But it was due to the wrong node version. If you use the latest jest `v29`, you need Node version 14 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

running jest directly from terminal i.e `npm jest` shows this error.

what worked for me was adding jest script in package.json file
i.e

```
{
  "scripts" : {
    "test":"jest"
  }
}
```

and then running `npm test` works.

--------- OR -------------

you can use ***npx*** to run jest commands directly from terminal
i.e `npx jest`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the test using `npx jest [parameters]`. `npx` is the package runner. It will help you execute a locally installed package.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just add [jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest?activeTab=versions) module to `package.json` dependencies.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

npx jest --init

or

./node_modules/.bin/jest --init