# Errors installing jest in console

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, console, jestjs

I'm attempting to install jest using a few different commands, but it's not installing correctly.

I've tried multiple commands, including everything on [command not found: jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138532/command-not-found-jest), as well as deleting any existing jest directories.

sudo npm install -g jest 
sudo npm install -g --save-dev jest

When I type jest -v, it says: -bash: jest: command not found

Here's the response I get when I ran the first npm install command:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.9 and node@12.2.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/lib'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1011:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: node install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

jest@24.8.0
added 479 packages from 342 contributors in 32.465s
```